# How to compute distance in discrete uniform grid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am a comp.sci. and am not sure if there is a more efficient way to to this: 
given a discreet uniform grid, compute distance between grid points, right now I do it with the pyth. thm. is there any other way since this is a discrete and uniform grid squares are fixed uniform size.
thanks.

Comment: The pythagorean theorem is probably the best way to go about this.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to calculate the Manhattan Distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)?

Comment: Are you finding the Pythagorean Theorem inefficient? Are these grids so massive you are running into problems squaring numbers, adding, and taking the square root?

Comment: It is a discrete layout algorithm that has a running time of n^3 so I wanted to see how I can improve it and it seemed like this type of calc. might have already been done.

Comment: @Adriano I need  the euclidean distance using the only the cell's width's and heights.

Comment: How is your running time $\Theta(n^3)$? What does $n$ represent? I'd imagine that using the Pythagorean Theorem would have a constant running time of $\Theta(1)$, since all you need to do is look up the points' coordinates and compute:
$$
\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}
$$

Comment: @Adriano Right, it is a force directed algorithm n^2 to compute forces run m number of times ~ n^3